# aggregation with $group stage and $sum operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to sum all "total" fields values using aggregation and group stage.
my code and documents is here

**documents**

```
{
    "_id": "57a068477b2l51ec16eb7das",
    "userID":"5742c6eedsaadsd93573e",
    "profileID":"5742aee49adv520593573c",
    "date": 1470130247779,
    "updateDate": 1470130361342,
    "total": 2
}
{
    "_id": "57a068477b2l51ec16eb983",
    "userID":"5742c6eedsaadsd93573e",
    "profileID":"5742aee49adv520593573c",
    "date": 1470130247779,
    "updateDate": 1470130361342,
    "total": 1
}
```

I'm doing below query for fetch sum of "total" values

```
    RecallProfile.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "updateDate": {
                    "$gte": from, "$lte": to
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": "$updateDate",
                "totalRecord": {"$sum": "$total"}
            }
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error ', err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
            console.log("result", result);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    })
```

Its giving "result []" log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try that, it is working. It looks like the issue is with from and to. In aggregation $match pipeline we need to have same type as field.You need `parseInt()` the variables as we get string form express request query.

```
"$match": {
    "updateDate": {
        "$gte": parseInt(from), "$lte": parseInt(to)
    }
}
```